# connection reset in spring integration ftp adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

### I am using spring integration's ftp down loader to download the files in the local directory. after sometimes it gives me the below error.

```
<bean id="ftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${ftp.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="$ftp.port}" />
        <property name="username" value="${ftp.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${ftp.password}" />
        <property name="clientMode" value="2" />
        <property name="fileType" value="2" />
        <property name="bufferSize" value="100000" />
</bean>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound" 
        channel="nullChannel" 
        session-factory="ftpSessionFactory" 
        charset="UTF-8" 
        delete-remote-files="false" 
        remote-directory="${ftp.remotedir}" 
        preserve-timestamp="true" 
        auto-create-local-directory="true" 
        local-directory="${ftp.localdir}" 
        filter="remoteFileListFilter" 
        temporary-file-suffix=".writing"> 
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" /> 
    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
</beans>
```

error is :

```
ERROR 2015-07-28 01:41:43,426 [task-scheduler-1][] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:193)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:167)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:124)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:284)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:278)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:311)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFileEntryParserImpl.readNextEntry(FTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:53)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPListParseEngine.readStream(FTPListParseEngine.java:128)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPListParseEngine.readServerList(FTPListParseEngine.java:104)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3302)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3271)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2930)
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.list(FtpSession.java:68)
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.list(FtpSession.java:41)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:171)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:302)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

It just means the server closed the connection - look at the server logs.

Comment: I am getting this error continuously, But still ftp downloader downloading the file in local dir and processing. Could you please explain it?

Comment: As I said, look at the server log.